# Hunchentoot test webserver usocket connection refused error

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot, usocket

Trying to start the Hunchentoot test webserver but usocket is throwing a connection error in Mac OSX El-Capitan, SBCL 1.1.6.0-3c5581a

```
debugger invoked on a USOCKET:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR:
  Condition USOCKET:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR was signalled.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(USOCKET::HANDLE-CONDITION #<SB-BSD-SOCKETS:CONNECTION-REFUSED-ERROR {14604771}> #<USOCKET:STREAM-USOCKET {145F7A91}>)
0]
```

Please help...

Comment: What were you trying to do at the time? What have you tried the do to cure this? What code is signaling this error?

Comment: Could you paste rest stacktrace and a part of the code where you start the server?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error with Hunchentoot on Linux, and the code works on Windows. SBCL 1.3.15. Tried running with sudo.

Comment: I have the same. But CCL works for me.